# Iterating through multiline input, and match to database items

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, flask, iteration, flask-sqlalchemy

I need help iterating through input to a webapp I'm writing, which looks like:

[image: input_shot]

The users will be inputting several hundred (or thousands) of urls pasted from excel documents, each on a new line like this. Thus far, as you can see, I've created the input page, an output page, and written the code to query the database.

```
from flask import Flask,render_template, request
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["DEBUG"] = True
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = "secret_key_here"
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = db.create_engine(connector_string_here))
app.config[SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI]  = SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_POOL_RECYCLE"] = 299
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = False

db.Model = declarative_base()
class Scrapers(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "Scrapers"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    scraper_dom = db.Column(db.String(255))
    scraper_id = db.Column(db.String(128))

db.Model.metadata.create_all(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI)

Session = db.sessionmaker()
Session.configure(bind=SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI)
session = Session()

scrapers = session.query(Scrapers.scraper_dom, Scrapers.scraper_id).all()

@app.route("/", methods=["GET","POST"])
def index():
    if request.method == "Get":
        return render_template("url_page.html")
    else:
        return render_template("url_page.html")

@app.route("/submit", methods=["GET","POST"])
def submit():
    sites = [request.form["urls"]]
    for site in sites:
        que = urlparse(site).netloc
    return render_template("submit.html", que=que)

#scrapers.filter(Scrapers.scraper_dom.in_(
#next(x.scraper_id for x in scrapers if x.matches(self.fnetloc))
```

As is apparent, this is incomplete. I've omitted previous attempts at matching the input, as I realized I had issues iterating through the input. At first, I could only get it to print all of the input instead of iterating over it. And now, it prints like this:

[image: output_shot]

Which is just repeating the `urlparse(site).netloc` for the first line of input, some random number of times. It is parsing correctly and returning the actual value I will need to use later (for each `urlparse(site).netloc` match scraper_dom and return associated scraper_id). Now, though, I've tried using `input()` but kept getting errors with `[request.form["urls"]]` not being an iterable.

Please help, it'd be much appreciated.

Output of sites:
[image: sites_output]

New output with:

```
que = [urlparse(site).netloc for site in request.form["urls"].split('\n')]
```

[image: without_for_loop]

Comment: Wondering if the text you're receiving from the text field just needs to be `.split('\n')`... since maybe the `.netloc()` call is only parsing one _long_ string, and grabs the first domain (alibaba.com), and then iterates for every character in the string...

Comment: Adding: 
`@app.route("/submit", methods=["GET","POST"])
def submit():
    sites = [request.form["urls"]].split('\n')
    for site in sites:
        que = urlparse(site).netloc
    return render_template("submit.html", que=que)`

Results in the error:
_2020-01-10 04:17:45,681: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'_

Comment: try a bare: `request.form["urls"].split('\n')` _without_ the enclosing `[...]` brackets... That makes what you are calling `.split()` on a list

Comment: Now it's doing the same thing as I originally posted, but with the last domain.
item.gmarket.co.kr

Comment: _*Oh!*_ you are passing in `que=que` to the template, and the last thing `que` is set to is the final site in the for loop. Try appending each site to a new list and iterating in your template, or even: eliminate the for loop and do: `que = [urlparse(site).netloc for site in request.form["urls"].split('\n')]`

Comment: Fixed my rendered template to iterate over `que` with `{% for q in que %}{{ q }}{% endfor %}` and it now prints the .netloc correctly. Thank you @Sparrow1029! Now, I just need to figure out how to pass the .netloc to a function that does the look up on the database data.